# Call bash script from php

Tags: php, bash, web

I need to capture user input on a web form and pass it to a script to create a user account but I cannot get it to work. so far I have a add_user.sh script that reads like this:

```
adduser -u $NAME -p $PASS -g users -s /bin/bash
```

but im not sure if that's going to capture user entered data from the web form?

Comment: you have to pass these parameters on the php command you're using to call add_user.sh. Something like this: `passthru("add_user.sh -u $NAME -p $PASS");`.

Comment: if `$NAME` is coming from a web form, then you had make **ABSOLUTELY** sure that you're using proper methods to pass that to a command line app. Consider what happens if the user enters `; rm -rf /` as their username... e.g. http://php.net/escape_shell_arg

Comment: Of course, what Marc B said is completely true.

Answer (score 2):

You can build it into a string and then use `exec` If your server has it enabled

```
$str = 'adduser -u ' . $NAME . ' -p ' . $PASS . ' -g users -s /bin/bash';
exec(escapeshellcmd($str));
```

I should have probably noted before, many hosts disable this and any functions that perform command line commands for security reasons. Just because this exists doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: Somewhat dangerous, depending on security settings and the data source of $NAME and $PASS.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php   http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: Marc B's comment to the OP applies as well. `$NAME` and `$PASS` have to be cleaned thoroughly before invoking the command.

Comment: Oh dear, this is rather dangerous `:)` **Don't use this method**

Comment: I edited my answer. quasivivo was right and I added that function in

Comment: I'd love to register with user name `gniourf -g admin` or something such `:)` **Please do not use this method.**

Answer (score 0):

Write your script `add_user.sh` like this (mind the quotes):

```
#!/bin/sh
adduser -u "$1" -p "$2" -g users -s /bin/bash
```

Render it executable:

```
me@somewhere$ chmod +x add_user.sh
```

And call it from within `php` as:

```
<?php
    $command="/path/to/add_user.sh ".escapeshellarg($name)." ".escapeshellarg($pass);
    exec ($command,$output=array(),$return_value);
    if($return_value!==0) {
        # Oh dear! something bad happened
    }
?>
```

(I don't have php installed here, so I can't thoroughly test my answer)

If you don't want to use your auxilliary script, you can directly do:

```
<?php
    $command="/path/to/adduser -u ".escapeshellarg($name)." -p ".escapeshellarg($pass)." -g users -s /bin/bash";
    exec ($command,$output=array(),$return_value);
    if($return_value!==0) {
        # Oh dear! something bad happened
    }
?>
```

Please make sure you test the return value (as I did). You'll have the command's output in the array `$output`.

Using `escapeshellarg` for each argument is much safer than calling `escapeshellcmd` on the already built in full command.